# X2GO client not forwarding keys like Ctrl and Alt

Tags: ubuntu, nx, kali-linux

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

X2GO server is on Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS ( Not a VM ).
X2GO client is on Kali Rolling Release ( Updated ).

Normally this would not be a problem but lets say I run a Terminal command like ping 8.8.8.8, I have to terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  Its also a pain when I'm trying to save something with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

And it's a real pain when I'm typing something and I have to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to cap a single letter.

Comment: For anyone stumbling onto this question, I have found to use the Super+ControlKey+Key works.  I don't know if this is an intended feature?

I have confirmed both sides use pc-105 keyboard configurations with a standard en-US keyboard

Comment: Another interesting thing.  Newest Teamviewer 13 for linux does the exact same thing, now this is the first Teamviewer version that uses Qt instead of wine, which makes me think this might be a bug in the OS itself not X2GO or Teamviewer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but there was no answer...
I found this, which worked for me (and others)

@glyndonwrote:
For me (Ubuntu 17.10), the fix was to turn off the "show mouse pointer location when Ctrl key pressed."

I had to use dconf-editor to locate that setting, as Ubuntu no longer includes it on the regular settings dialog panel.

(in dconf-editor: org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse)

Comment: Thnx dude, will try that if i ever use x2go again

Answer (score 0):

Taking the hint from answer #1, I found a similar setting under "org/gnome/desktop/interface/locate-pointer", which is what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

just disable Pointer Location from tweaks

[tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1jia.png)